# Pulling HREF using DomDocument only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I would like to pull the HREF from the following html output

```
<div class="course">
    <p class="course-data">
        <a class="course-name i13n-sec-country i13n-ltxt-meeting i13n-tab-TODO-TAG-TAB" href="/course?courseId=1.2&amp;date=20150713">
            Ayr
        </a> | SOFT
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li class="full" title="7f 50yds Maiden Stakes | 10 runners">
            <a class="i13n-sec-country i13n-ltxt-race i13n-tab-TODO-TAG-TAB" href="/raceresult?raceId=1.2.1150713.1">
                09:00
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="full" title="1m Handicap | 5 runners">
            <a class="i13n-sec-country i13n-ltxt-race i13n-tab-TODO-TAG-TAB" href="/raceresult?raceId=1.2.1150713.2">
                09:30
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="full" title="1m2f Handicap | 6 runners">
            <a class="i13n-sec-country i13n-ltxt-race i13n-tab-TODO-TAG-TAB" href="/raceresult?raceId=1.2.1150713.3">
                10:00
            </a>
        </li>
```

But I only want the href attribute if the call contains the word "race" - for eg it would pull this href

```
<a class="i13n-sec-country i13n-ltxt-race i13n-tab-TODO-TAG-TAB" href="/raceresult?raceId=1.2.1150713.1">
```

I have tried myself but cant seem to pull the href using `getAttribute('href')` and get the error "Call to a member function item() on a non-object"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$tagList = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($tagList as $tag) {
    // Simple string check, but beware using strstr and utf-8
    if(strstr($tag->getAttribute('class'), 'race')) {
        echo $tag->getAttribute('href');
    }
}
```

or you can use SimpleXML

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
$tagList = $xml->xpath("//a[contains(@class,'race')]");
foreach ($tagList as $tag) {
    var_dump($tag->attributes()['href']);
}
```

Comment: This is what im looking for!... how would you only pull href if the class contains 'race' ??? OR even better would be only pulling those where 'raceresult' was in the href

Comment: Im trying to make it work like this `$getdropdown             = '//div[contains(@data-location, "RACING_COUNTRY_GB_IE")]//div[contains(@class, "course")]';
$getdropdown2            = $xpath->query($getdropdown);

$getdropdown2  = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
//loop through each individual card
foreach ($getdropdown2 as $dropresults) {
echo $href = $dropresults->getAttribute('href')."<br />";
 }`

Comment: Use `preg_match` to see if the href contains `raceresult`

Comment: Yeah you could preg_match or alternatively use SimpleXML and that has an xpath, I'll update my example for you;